# Form has Event handler attached to it from the web resource

Tags: dynamics-crm

I have a marketing list form which has its own OnLoad event attached to it, upon inspecting Form properties I see that there are no libraries added just an event:

[image]

this aforementioned .js file does not exist in Web resources.

My question:

- Where should I look for it ?

Comment: Did you try that “Edit library” button above Event grid?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely this is Microsoft OOB web resource library (Internal use only). If this is not bothering you and if you don’t need it, leave it as it is. Even you can remove the event registered in form editor, no harm will be made - possibly some section which is hidden may be shown or vice versa. But, you cannot add it back since library dropdown will be empty when you try to register it back.

It could be mistakenly registered/failed to remove during some upgrades. MS team failure. :(

on a quick search - I see only [this reference](https://crmtipoftheday.com/1154/when-unified-interface-misbehaves/) in internet for that file.

[image]

I remember I have seen such mess related to Field service libraries and LinkedIn integration libraries not registered in Account/Contact forms and only events were there.

Even if you try to find the library in default solution, when you open it - it will be condensed and read-only. :)